# Android OneNote API app launch error

Tags: android, onenote-api

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to work through this tutorial making a [Android OneNote API app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575422.aspx) and it's pretty straightforward but I get a launch error when i try to run it.

Session 'app': Error Launching activity

Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity

Here's a copy of my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ResultsActivity"></activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you must define the launcher activity in your manifest

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'll do some research on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There sould be something like this in your manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You need specificly this line

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

to tell the system the starting point of your app, in this case the activity

```
".Splash"
```

Comment: Thank you, for your help. I popped that code into my manifest and replaced the "@string/app_name" field with one relevant to my project. Unfortunately I'm getting the same error. I'll keep at it and post when I figure out the solution. Thanks again for your time.